# Slick carousel with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slide, slick.js

I'm using slick carousel in my project and it's not working properly.when I load data from the database through ajax it shows data but do not show as needed.slick's javascript or jquery are not loaded so, it does not look like a slide.

html part,

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="responsive slidermenu" id="get_category">
        <!--
            <div class="cat-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-book">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="menuimg" src="../Dv/upload/category/" alt=""/>
                        <a href=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and ajax part

```
function category_c(){
    $.ajax({
        url :   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :{category:1},
        success :function(data){
            $("#get_category").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

PHP part,

```
if(isset($_POST["category"])){
    $category_query = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$category_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
            $cid = $row["category_id"];
            $cat_name = $row["category_name"];
            $cat_image = $row["category_icon"];
            echo "
                <div class='cat-image-wrapper'>
                    <div class='single-book'>
                        <div class='text-center'>
                            <img class='menuimg' src='../Dv/upload/category/$cat_image'/>
                            <a href=''>$cat_name</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not call the `slick`'s slide / init method

Comment: You most likely need to move your slick setup into the success function of the ajax call, after `$("#get_category").html(data);`